# Shrink space between lines

Tags: spacing

I'm writing an article in LaTeX. In the last paragraph of conclusion section, the space between lines shrinks unexpectedly. I do not understand what is happening. How can I make things have uniform spacing?

[image]

The link for testing on Overleaf is below:

https://www.overleaf.com/8292319135hqrvdnmywszc

Comment: There's also a spacing anomaly in the third paragraph of section 7, but there the space is wider, so it's slightly less obvious.

Comment: ...also remove the spurious `\vspace`s that are placed within paragraphs (the cause behind @barbarabeeton's comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `strip` environment for the set of equations you list. Instead, use a `figure*` environment to allow the block of equations to flow to the next page (across both columns) and then reword you paragraph to identify the equations you're referencing. Something like:

> As mentioned section 3, the robot dynamics requires matrices related to its inertial movement. Their definitions are in equations (10)-(13) below for reference.

[image]

```
As mentioned in section \ref{sec:dynamics_control}, the robot dynamics 
requires matrices related to its inertial movement. Their definitions 
are in equations (\ref{eq:M})-(\ref{eq:nu}) below for reference. 

\begin{figure*}[t]
    % your equations here
\end{figure*}

% rest of your document
```

I added a `\label{eq:M}` for the first equation in order to reference it properly.

Comment: Nice. Thank you for the advice. Out-of-the-box solution

Comment: I don't want to open a new question. Because of that, could you help me understanding why do the table captions appear hyphenized?

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto: The use of the [`caption` package](//ctan.org/pkg/caption) (or [`subcaption`](//ctan.org/subcaption) which includes `caption`) causes the problem - the class defines their own way of handling `\caption`s depending on whether it's a `figure` or `table`. Adding `\usepackage{caption}` or `\usepackage{subcaption}` already reports a warning in the `.log` of an unknown package/class, and then redefines the way `\caption` works... this is the root of the problem. You should redo your figures to use a `tabular` structure for layout out sub-figures; that would be my suggestion.

Comment: I want to fix only the table. Is it possible without redefinition of all figures?